# Range and Runtime error 1004 : Method range of object - 'Global' failed

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to combine data on two spreadsheets into one resultant sheet by multiplying units and dollars from one tab by a % attachment rate on another tab. It seems the formula is getting an error in the 'Range' but I am not a programmer and have not been able to parse through this with MS Excel online literature and the Stack Overflow posts I've seen (looks like a similar problem to [VBA getting runtime error when trying sum function on named range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52493457/vba-getting-runtime-error-when-trying-sum-function-on-named-range)).

The individual who originally wrote the code is not available to assist. Thanks so much for any guidance!

Error is on the following code:

```
Dim bContinue As Boolean
    bContinue = Range("Calc.Inputs.Exists").Value   'only continue if the ID returns a valid record. _
        When the macro reaches beyond the last record, this will turn false and the macro will terminate.
```

---

Full script below...

```
Sub Splits_Generator()
'Check if user wants to continue
Dim vResponse As Variant
    vResponse = MsgBox("This will take a 2-5 minutes to complete. " & _
        "The Excel screen will appear unresponsive during this time.  Do you wish to continue?", vbOKCancel + vbQuestion)
    If vResponse = vbCancel Then
        MsgBox "Action Canceled!", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Set application settings and timer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Dim t1 As Date
    t1 = Timer


    'Initialize a few variables
Dim OutputsHeaders() As Variant
    OutputsHeaders = Range("Outputs[#Headers]").Value    'Loads Outputs headers into an array.
Dim dictColNum As Object
    Set dictColNum = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        'Creating dictionary object to keep track of the column numbers where the Outputs header _
        items are located on the Calc page
Dim dictFormula As Object
    Set dictFormula = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        'Creating dictionary object.  Contains the formula used to calculate the column if the _
        column's values are calculated on the Outputs page.

    'Find the column numbers for each header item
Dim x As Long
    For x = 1 To UBound(OutputsHeaders, 2)
        On Error Resume Next
        dictColNum.Item(OutputsHeaders(1, x)) = _
            Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(OutputsHeaders(1, x), Range("Calc.Header"), 0)
                'Lookup the column number
        If Err <> 0 Then
                'If no number was found, this means there is a column on the Outputs page that is _
                not found on the Calc page
            dictColNum.Item(OutputsHeaders(1, x)) = Empty
                'In this case, we have no column number so it is set to empty
            If Mid(Range("Outputs[#Headers]").Cells(2, x).Formula, 1, 1) = "=" Then
                    'Check if the values in this Outputs column are calculated on the Outputs page _
                    (usually every thing should be calculated on the Calc page so this is just _
                    preparing for the possibility that a calculation could have been _
                    done on the Outputs page itself). Otherwise the calculation would be _
                    overwritten and the formula lost.
                dictFormula.Item(OutputsHeaders(1, x)) = Range("Outputs[#Headers]").Cells(2, x).FormulaR1C1
                    'The formula in the first row of data will be used for the whole column. _
                    This assumes the same calculation is used on the whole column, which should _
                    be a fair assumption since we are using defined tables
            Else
                dictFormula.Item(OutputsHeaders(1, x)) = Empty  'If not a formula and not found on the Calc page, then the data will be overwritten
            End If
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next

    'Delete old data
    Application.GoTo "Outputs"
    Range("Outputs").AutoFilter
        'Turns off AutoFilter.  If left on and data is filtered, then the macro will produce incorrect _
        results
    Range("Outputs[#Data]").ClearContents

    'Initialize more variables
Dim InitialRecordCounter As Long
    InitialRecordCounter = Range("Calc.ID").Value
        'Remember which IDs were set before the macro started
Dim InitialSplitsID As Variant
    InitialSplitsID = Range("Calc.Splits.ID").Formula
        'Remember which IDs were set before the macro started
Dim RecordCounter As Long   'Count of records processed from the "Inputs" sheet
    RecordCounter = 1
    Range("Calc.ID") = RecordCounter 'Calc starts with record one
    Range("Calc.ID").Worksheet.Calculate 'Force sheet to recalculate
Dim ArrayCounter As Long    'Count of records currently loaded into the array
    ArrayCounter = 0
Dim OutputsRecordCounter As Long    'Total number of records added to the "Outputs" sheet
    OutputsRecordCounter = 0
Dim LastOutputsRecordLoaded As Long
        'The number of records in the "Outputs" sheet when data was last loaded into it
    LastOutputsRecordLoaded = 0
Dim Outputs() As Variant
    ReDim Outputs(1 To UBound(OutputsHeaders, 2), 1 To 1)
        'This array has the same number of rows as the number of columns in the Outputs Header.
        'Data must be flipped on its side to allow the array to add more records. _
        New records can only be added on the 2nd dimension.
Dim bContinue As Boolean
    bContinue = Range("Calc.Inputs.Exists").Value   'only continue if the ID returns a valid record. _
        When the macro reaches beyond the last record, this will turn false and the macro will terminate.

Dim bFirstInvalid As Boolean    'True until at least one invalid record has been found
    bFirstInvalid = True
Dim InvalidRow As Long
Dim InvalidSheetCount As Long
InvalidSheetCount = 1
Dim sInvalidSheetName As String
sInvalidSheetName = "Invalid Records"
Dim wsInvalid As Worksheet

    Do While bContinue
Dim SplitsCounter As Long  'Count of number of Splits per Input record
        Range("Calc.Splits.ID").Value = 1 & " " _
                & Range("Calc.Type").Value    'Update the Splits ID to the next Splits record
        Range("Calc.Splits.ID").Worksheet.Calculate 'Force sheet to recalculate
        For SplitsCounter = 1 To Range("Calc.SplitsCount").Value 'Represents the number of rows that each Inputs row will be split into
            Range("Calc.Splits.ID").Value = SplitsCounter & " " _
                & Range("Calc.Type").Value    'Update the Splits ID to the next Splits record
            Range("Calc.Splits.ID").Worksheet.Calculate 'Force sheet to recalculate
            If Range("Calc.ValidRecord").Value Then
                    'If the record is not valid, it will skip processing it.  For example, the user _
                    can set a condition that the total volume or revenue has to be above a certain _
                    threshold.  If not, then it will not make it to the Outputs page.  The purpose _
                    of this condition is to eliminate rows from the Output page that do not provide _
                    meaningful or accurate information.  It reduces processing time and lowers file size.
                If Range("Calc.Splits.Exists").Value Then
                    ArrayCounter = ArrayCounter + 1
                    OutputsRecordCounter = OutputsRecordCounter + 1
                    ReDim Preserve Outputs(1 To UBound(Outputs, 1), 1 To ArrayCounter)
                        'Expand the array to allow values to be inserted for this record
                    For x = 1 To UBound(Outputs, 1)
                        If dictColNum.Item(OutputsHeaders(1, x)) <> Empty Then
                                'If the column number is not an empty value, then the Calc page has a _
                                calculated value we can use
                            Outputs(x, ArrayCounter) = _
                                Range("Calc.Output").Cells(1, dictColNum.Item(OutputsHeaders(1, x))).Value
                                    'Set the value of this element of the array
                        Else
                                'If the column number is an empty value that means there is not a column _
                                with a matching name in the Calc page
                            If dictFormula.Item(OutputsHeaders(1, x)) = Empty Then
                                    'We're checking whether this column has a formula we should use from _
                                    the Outputs page
                                Outputs(x, ArrayCounter) = Empty
                                    'If not, then we set the field value to empty
                            Else
                                Outputs(x, ArrayCounter) = dictFormula.Item(OutputsHeaders(1, x))
                                    'If so, then we use the formula we found earlier in the code
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next
                    If OutputsRecordCounter Mod 2000 = 0 Then
                            'Reports the current record to the user as the macro is running. _
                            It is pre-set to report at increments of 2000.  This is somewhat arbitrary. _
                            However, I did find that if you set the number too low, i.e., reporting _
                            very frequently, then the macro performance deterioriates.
                        Application.StatusBar = "Current Record: " & OutputsRecordCounter
                        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                    End If
                    If ArrayCounter Mod 10000 = 0 Then
                            'I found that processing the data in blocks of 10k records keeps memory _
                            from getting clogged and results in a 2x performance increase in the macro
                        Outputs = MyTranspose(Outputs)
                            'As mentioned earlier, the data had to be loaded into a transposed array. _
                            Now we transpose it back.
                        Range(Range("Outputs[#Headers]").Offset(LastOutputsRecordLoaded + 1, 0), _
                            Range("Outputs[#Headers]").Offset(LastOutputsRecordLoaded + ArrayCounter, 0)).FormulaR1C1 _
                            = Outputs
                                'Load the data onto the Outputs page
                        LastOutputsRecordLoaded = OutputsRecordCounter
                        ArrayCounter = 0
                        ReDim Outputs(1 To UBound(OutputsHeaders, 2), 1 To 1)
                            'This array has the same number of rows as the number of columns in the _
                            Outputs Header.  Data must be flipped on its side to allow the array to _
                            add more records.  New records can only be added on the 2nd dimension.
                    End If
                Else
                    If bFirstInvalid Then
                        'If we have not already had at least one invalid record, then we will need to prep _
                        the sheet for the first use
                        bFirstInvalid = False
                        Set wsInvalid = Worksheets.Add
                        Do
                            Err = 0
                            On Error Resume Next
                            If InvalidSheetCount = 1 Then
                                wsInvalid.Name = sInvalidSheetName
                            Else
                                wsInvalid.Name = sInvalidSheetName & " (" & InvalidSheetCount & ")"
                            End If
                            InvalidSheetCount = InvalidSheetCount + 1
                        Loop Until Err = 0
                        On Error GoTo 0
                        wsInvalid.Range("A1") = "Inputs ID"
                        wsInvalid.Range("B1") = "Splits ID"
                        InvalidRow = 2
                    End If
                    wsInvalid.Cells(InvalidRow, 1) = Range("Calc.ID")
                    wsInvalid.Cells(InvalidRow, 2) = Range("Calc.Splits.ID")
                    InvalidRow = InvalidRow + 1
                End If
            Else
                If bFirstInvalid Then
                    'If we have not already had at least one invalid record, then we will need to prep _
                    the sheet for the first use
                    bFirstInvalid = False
                    Set wsInvalid = Worksheets.Add
                    Do
                        Err = 0
                        On Error Resume Next
                        If InvalidSheetCount = 1 Then
                            wsInvalid.Name = sInvalidSheetName
                        Else
                            wsInvalid.Name = sInvalidSheetName & " (" & InvalidSheetCount & ")"
                        End If
                        InvalidSheetCount = InvalidSheetCount + 1
                    Loop Until Err = 0
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    wsInvalid.Range("A1") = "Inputs ID"
                    wsInvalid.Range("B1") = "Splits ID"
                    InvalidRow = 2
                    wsInvalid.Cells(1, 1).AutoFilter
                        'Turn on autofilter on invalids sheet
                End If
                wsInvalid.Cells(InvalidRow, 1) = Range("Calc.ID")
                wsInvalid.Cells(InvalidRow, 2) = "All"
                InvalidRow = InvalidRow + 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        RecordCounter = RecordCounter + 1
        Range("Calc.ID") = RecordCounter 'Update the ID to the next record
        Range("Calc.ID").Worksheet.Calculate 'Force sheet to recalculate
        bContinue = Range("Calc.Inputs.Exists").Value   'only continue if the ID returns a value record
    Loop

    If ArrayCounter > 0 Then
            'If there are any data not loaded into the Outputs page (under the 10k threshold), _
            then take care of the remainder.
        Outputs = MyTranspose(Outputs)
            'As mentioned earlier, the data had to be loaded into a transposed array. _
            Now we transpose it back.
        Range(Range("Outputs[#Headers]").Offset(LastOutputsRecordLoaded + 1, 0), _
            Range("Outputs[#Headers]").Offset(LastOutputsRecordLoaded + ArrayCounter, 0)).FormulaR1C1 = Outputs
                'Load the data onto the Outputs page
    End If


'End of macro code
    Range("Outputs").Worksheet.ListObjects("Outputs").Resize Range("Outputs").CurrentRegion
        'Reset the size of the Outputs range to align to the size of the data added. _
        This can come into play if the previous set of data had been larger.  There will be _
        blank rows in the table in this case.
    Range("Outputs").AutoFilter
        'Put the autofilter back on
    Range("Calc.ID") = InitialRecordCounter
        'Reset the yellow highlighted values on the Calc page to their pre-macro values
    Range("Calc.Splits.ID").Value = InitialSplitsID
        'Reset the yellow highlighted values on the Calc page to their pre-macro values
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
        'Refresh all pivot tables
    Set dictColNum = Nothing    'Set objects to nothing.  Helps keep memory clean
    Set dictFormula = Nothing    'Set objects to nothing.  Helps keep memory clean
    Set wsInvalid = Nothing     'Set objects to nothing.  Helps keep memory clean
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.StatusBar = False
Dim t2 As Date
    t2 = Timer - t1
    MsgBox "Done.  This took " & IIf(t2 > 60, Format(Int(t2 / 60), "0") & " min ", "") & Format(t2 Mod 60, "0") & " seconds to complete."

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you actually have a range called `"Calc.Inputs.Exists"`? That's the name of it? And it exists in the `ActiveSheet` - whatever that is at the time?

Comment: There's an implicit `ActiveSheet` too. The error means there is no `Range` with that name on the active sheet.

Comment: Yes. It is a True/False based on whether the Calc.ID exists on an Inputs sheet.

Comment: If that `Range` exists, then the sheet it exists on is not the `ActiveSheet`. You should qualify the `Worksheet` (and `Workbook`). Anytime you have a `Range` call, the `Worksheet` and `Workbook` should be qualified.

Comment: Thank you. Could you give an example of where/how that might be done? 

Workbook before the range? 
OutputsHeaders = *Workbook*.Range("Outputs[#Headers]").Value

Comment: `Range("Outputs[#Headers]")` is (IMO) a "cheat" way to get at the range of a table, without specifying what worksheet the table is on. I would use a `ListObject` to refer to the table here. But in general it is `Workbook.Worksheet.Range`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks again. I'll run with this and see if I can get it.